# How we can detect phone flip event in the flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flip

I have a requirement where I have to turn on or off the visibility of an element when the user flips the phone.

- When user flip for the first time then hide the element
- If user do flip again then show the element.

Flip event callback should only be recognized when user flip the phone horizontally (I mean X-axis wise) not vertically(Y-axis)

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/sensors/latest/sensors/GyroscopeEvent-class.html

Comment: @OzanTaskiran Could you please help me out with the sensors logic, I have used the above package and GyroscopeEvent but not getting the accurate event logic for the flip animation.